# RoR routing error in "hello world"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn web-dev and decided to learn ruby on rails. I'm doing the first tutorial from "Agile Web Development with Rails". I've seen there are quite a few search results on google, but all the recommendation is "to restart the server", which does not help my case.

So, I started webrick and generate controller Say with these code:

```
def hello
end
```

and then I added hello.rhtml, which has some basic html with message "Hello from rails".

When i type in browser: http://localhost:3000/say/hello

I get : No route matches [GET] "/say/hello"

I tried to restart webrick, doesn't work. The bug-name suggest it has to do with routes, i've got two versions of the book, none of them have the steps to alter the routes.rb and within routes.rb i have commented-out stuff and class definition.

Does anyone know what should i do?

Comment: You should show us your routes, otherwise we'd just be guessing.

Comment: it was just empty class with comments (e.g. everything in it was commented out). The solution provided by Nobita solved my problem.

Comment: Better to provide that kind of info in the beginning, although I'd have to think having a completely empty routes file would be a clue as to why nothing was being routed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing is a problem in your routes file. You need to define what you want rails to do (which controller+action you want to be perform) when that URL is received. So, do the following:

```
match 'say/hello', :to => "say#hello"
```

This will tell rails that when a URL with say/hello is received, the hello action of the controller say has to be performed.